# How can i use the if statement in ngfor?

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have a loop of 5 buttons and I want to disable the second button, so I tried with using the `*ngIf` inside the `*ngFor` but its not working correctly for me. Can you help me? Thanks!

```
<div *ngFor="let day of days">
  <div *ngIf="day == dayFinished ">
    <ion-button id={{day}} expand="block" size="large (click)="test(day)"ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days"  disabled >DAY {{day}}</ionbutton>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this

If you want to disable the second button in a loop then you can set `i==1` (because index always start from 0)

```
<div *ngFor="let day of days; let i=index">
<div *ngIf="day == dayFinished ">
  <ion-button id={{day}} expand="block" size="large (click)="test(day)" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days" [disabled]="i==1" >DAY {{day}}</ionbutton>
</div>
```

I hope this will be useful

Answer (score 2):

You can use function in ngFor instead of array like this

in your html=>

```
<div *ngFor="let day of filterDays()">
  <ion-button id={{day}} expand="block" size="large (click)="test(day)"ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days" disabled >DAY {{day}}</ionbutton>
```

in your component=>

```
filterDays(){
  return days.filter(x => x.day == "dayFinished");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use index with `ngFor`.

Here is the way you can do

```
<div *ngFor="let day of days; let i=index">
<div *ngIf="day == dayFinished ">
  <ion-button id={{day}} expand="block" size="large (click)="test(day)"ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days"  [disabled]="i==1" >DAY {{day}}</ionbutton>
</div>
```

`index` always start from 0 so check `i==1`

Comment: Thanks! I didnt use the ngIf at all! I just added the " i=index".

Comment: So accept my answer please if my asnwer worked for you

Comment: I have an other question.Can i make the index an array ? To explain this.Lets say i finiish day 1 so i want to disable button 1 next the day 2 and disable button 1 and 2 until the last day....I hope you understand what i mean.

Comment: can you please ask this in a separate question with your code having your object containing arrays so that i can get a better idea

Comment: the code is this :   <div *ngFor="let day of days let i=index">
    <ion-button id={{day}} expand="block" size="large" (click)="test(day)" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days" [disabled]="i==dayFinished" >DAY {{day}}</ion-button>
  </div>

The issue is that when i change the i from 1 to 2 the button only the button 2 is 
 disabled.Then if i change to 3 the only the 3.But i want all of them to be disabled.

Comment: Please ask this in another stackoverflow question with proper formatting so that i can get better understanding. In this way your code seems a mess. Please ask this in another question

Comment: Check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55494515/disable-buttons-in-ngfor-loop