# disable buttons in ngFor loop

Tags: angular, ngfor

I want to disable buttons inside by `ngFor` loop.I set the `i-index` inside `ngFor` but the issue is that it only disables the button with the id of i.If i want to disable multiple buttons inside this loop what should i do?

Lets say i have 5 buttons.I want to disable the button number 1.After i want to disable 2.With this code when i change to 2 the 1 goes back to enable.

```
<div *ngFor="let day of days let i=index">
    <ion-button id={{day}} expand="block" size="large" (click)="test(day)" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days" [disabled]="i==dayFinished" >DAY {{day}}</ion-button>
</div>
```

And in the **.ts** file :

```
   dayFinished = null;
   this.dayFinished = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id");
   this.dayFinished -= 1;
```

Comment: You need to take object array for the items

Comment: what is day of days?

Comment: can you share your array of object also?

Comment: days is an array of 30 items. days[1,2,...]

Comment: if you want to disable days finished then  you should be using `[disabled]="i <= dayFinished"`

Comment: thanks @JoelJoseph it works!

Comment: @Retry Ok i will post it as answer , please mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to disable days  that you have clicked then

html

```
<div *ngFor="let day of days let i=index">
    <ion-button id={{day}} expand="block" size="large" (click)="test(day)" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days" [disabled]="checkIfFinnished(day)" >DAY {{day}}</ion-button>
 </div>
```

In component.ts file

```
   dayFinished = [];

   this.dayFinished.push(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get("id"));


  test(day){
   if(this.dayFinished.includes(day)){
      this.dayFinished.splice(this.dayFinished.indexOf(day),1);
   }
   else
   { 
    this.dayFinished.push(day);
   }
  }

  checkIfFinnished(item){
     return  this.dayFinished.includes(item);
   }
```

Comment: so are you trying to disable the days that you have clicked  ?  or the ones that are less than the finished date , please explain what are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yep im trying to disable the days that i clicked.

Answer (score 1):

You can use an array of object like this [{day: 1, disabled: true}, {day: 2, disabled: false}], then you use the property 'disabled' for the accessibility and the 'day' to display
You do the logic for the true/false in the component

```
<div *ngFor="let item of objectArray let i=index">
    <ion-button id={{item.day}} expand="block" size="large" (click)="test(item.day)" ngDefaultControl [(ngModel)]="days" [disabled]="item.disabled" >DAY {{item.day}}</ion-button>
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Clean solution.